# Property value different in Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

For some reason the IsFiltered property is set to true in the EnterPressed method. Once entering the Task, the property then comes back as false. Once leaving the Task however it returns back to true (then false in the Remove Progress method).

What am I missing? Can someone provide a link or tutorial that could point me in the right direction.

Using C#, Caliburn Micro and VS2017.

```
public bool IsFiltering
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool ShowGrid
    {
        get
        {
            return !this.IsFiltering;
        }
    }

    public void SetProgress()
    {
        this.IsFiltering = true;

        NotifyOfPropertyChange("IsFiltering");
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("ShowGrid");
    }

public void EnterPressed()
    {
        SetProgress();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (this.searchFilter != "")
            {
                var filtered = Expenses.Where(exp => exp.ExpenseDescription.StartsWith(searchFilter.ToUpper())).ToList();
                var obsFiltered = new ObservableCollection<Models.Expense>(filtered);
                this.transactionReader.Expenses = obsFiltered;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Expenses);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("EnterPressed called :: searchFilter is: " + this.searchFilter);
        });

        RemoveProgress();
    }
```

Comment: did you mean the `IsFiltering` property? you aren't showing `IsFiltered`

Comment: Yes that’s what I mean sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `await` your task. That means your `Task.Run` maybe executes after  `RemoveProgress`. So, this is the flow of execution

`SetProgress` set `true`, then, it executes `RemoveProgress`, your property is still `true`.

`RemoveProgress` receives your property as `true` and sets it to `false`. Next, it runs the task, and your property is `false` inside it.

Try to organize your code, think about `await` or `ContinueWith` the task

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Run` schedules work *on the thread pool* - i.e. at some undefined point in the future. What you have is basically:

- mark it in progress
- schedule some work to happen *at some undefined point in the future*
- mark it not in progress

In almost all cases, the thread-pool won't have even *dequeued* that item by the time you mark it not in progress, let alone started running it.

Maybe mark it in-progress/not-in-progress *as part of the scheduled work*, i.e. *inside* the `Task.Run()` callback.